# reading vaues from table and editing text file with that values using bash

Tags: bash, text, edit

hi I am a beginner and learning bash scripting..

I have two files one is data table data.dat and another text file input.in

data.dat looks like this

```
a b c d 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

and input.in looks like

```
rc duct.gz
fi as df 500
def bc pff p 1 n 2 n 3 n 4 n n n 
def bc po p 1 n 2 y n n n
```

now i want to replace the values in text file such as 1 2 3 4 with that of 5 6 7 8 from the table and save text file with some other name input2.in
and next time 1 2 3 4 should replace with 1 3 5 7 and save with other name input3.in
like this till it completes the table

Comment: so far what i understood is read the table line by line and store the values in variable like this is it right

while read a b c d
do
        echo "a : $a"  
 echo "b : $b" 
 echo "c : $c" 
 echo "d : $d"
done < data.dat  

now i want to read the text file and insert these values to perticuler locations in the text file can u help me out how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

```
a=4
line="this is line with parameter a=$a"
eval echo ${line}
```

EDIT: extended answer.
You need two nested loops. In external one you read values from data.dat into a,b,c and d variables. The internal one reads the file input.in and for each read line you need to display it with eval echo. Just make sure you put $a, $b, $c and $d in proper places, like:

```
def bc pff p $a n $b n $c n $d n n n
```

Comment: i appreciate your help Artur
so far what i understood is read the table line by line and store the values in variable like this is it right

while read a b c d
do
        echo "a : $a"  
 echo "b : $b" 
 echo "c : $c" 
 echo "d : $d"
done < data.dat  

now I want to read the text file and insert these values to perticuler locations in the text file can you help me out how to do that